# Añadir diccionarios a una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un diccionario de participaciones a partido de fútbol y me gustaria saber cuantos nuevas personas (personas que nadie vengan) hay cada semanas:

```
matchs = {
    "match-1":
      {
          "date": "2-6-2021",
          "joueurs": [
                {"name": "Pierre-Irénée Perrin", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Ivanne Combe Laboissière", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Domitille Croizier des Hormais", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Blanche d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Augustin Debouy", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Amaury Mabille du Chêne", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Pierrick Vignon", "sex":"m"}
          ]
      },
      "match-2":{
          "date": "9-6-2021",
          "joueurs": [
                {"name": "Clotilde Grange", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Claire Dlm", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Domitille Croizier des Hormais", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Ombeline d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Blanche d'Harcourt", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Humbert Frécon", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Antoine", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Willy DM", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Aude Simonin", "sex":"f"},
                {"name": "Amaury Mabille du Chêne", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Pierrick Vignon", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Andrea Radici", "sex":"m"},
                {"name": "Stanislas Dupuis", "sex":"m"}
            ]
      }
}
```

Y mucho mas...

Y me gustaria saber cuantos nuevas mujeres y hombres hay mor un aqui:

```
numbers = []
anciens = []
for match in matchs.items():
  females = 0
  males = 0
  new_f =0
  new_m = 0
  for joueur in match[1]["joueurs"]:
    if joueur["sex"] == "f":
      females +=1
    else:
      males+=1
    # calculemos los nuevos jugadores
    if joueur not in anciens:
      print("anciens", anciens)
      print("joueur", joueur)
      if joueur["sex"] == "f":
        new_f+=1
      else:
        new_m+=1
      # recordamos los ancianos
      anciens += joueur
  numbers.append([match[1]["date"], males, females, new_m, new_f])
```

Pero obtengo:

```
    date    males   females new_f   new_m
0   2-6-2021    5   4   5   4
1   9-6-2021    7   6   7   6
```

Que no es verdad para la seconda linea porque hay personas que fue  la primera partido ...

En efecto, parece que sigue anadido solo las claves...

```
anciens []
joueur {'name': 'Pierre-Irénée Perrin', 'sex': 'm'}
anciens ['name', 'sex']
joueur {'name': 'Ivanne Combe Laboissière', 'sex': 'f'}
anciens ['name', 'sex', 'name', 'sex']
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando agregas los jugadores a `anciens` no estás haciendo realmente lo que te propones.

```
anciens += joueur
```

Como lo explicaste lo que sucede al aplicar `[list] += [dict]` es que agrega solamente las llaves:

```
>>> j4 = {'name': 'Antoine', 'sex': 'm'}
>>> a = []
>>> a += j4
>>> a
['name', 'sex']
>>> j4 in a
False
>>>
```

Lo que debería hacer es `lista.append(el_dict)`:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append(j4)
>>> a
[{'name': 'Antoine', 'sex': 'm'}]
>>> j4 in a
True
>>>
```

En resumen, esto debería solucionar el problema:

```
anciens.append(joueur)
```

## Extra [Para Python < 3.7]

Esta línea `for match in matchs.items():` no garantiza retornar las llaves en el orden que las declaraste. En este caso, no hay garantía que `match-1` va a venir antes de `match-2`.

Comment: A partir de python 3.7, los diccionarios conservan el mismo orden de las claves que se usó en su creación, pasando a ser parte de la [especificación del lenguaje](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).